# Passing information between web pages in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an Image Gallery System where I'm building a feature to edit the attributes of an uploaded image.

```
@login_required
def edit(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ZSN = request.POST['ZSN']
        ZSN = 'images/' + ZSN + '.'

        image = Images.objects.filter(file__startswith=ZSN)

        if image:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/photo-edit', {'image':image})
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid ZSN.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'cms/edit.html')
```

This is my `edit` method in `views.py`. Notice that I am getting the `image` object as the image whose attributes has to be edited. If the image is found then I'm redirecting to home/photo-edit where I want to display a HTML page containing a **form with image attributes, pre-filled with existing attributes**.

My views.py method for home/photo-edit/ URL is

```
@login_required
def photoedit(request):
    return render(request, 'cms/photo-edit.html', {'image':image})
```

But image here isn't getting recognised even though I am sending it from `home/edit` to `home/photo-edit`. How do I do this? Is he syntax wrong?

Comment: You have to somehow obtain the image value before you actually send it. This value is not known in your view.

Comment: image = Images.objects.filter(file__startswith=ZSN) Isn't this doing that?

Comment: The body of `home/photo-edit/` does not have it at all - it has to happen somehwere between `def photoedit(request):` and `return`

Comment: yes it does but also should be fetched in the photoedit view. add this line to your photoedit. image = Images.objects.filter(file__startswith=ZSN)

Comment: But photoedit doesn't contain a ZSN, right?

Comment: You should have something in the URL, e.g. `home/photo-edit/{image_pk}` to identify the image from the request.

Comment: I basically want a method, HTML page for accepting an Id (ZSN) and search that in the DB. One more method, HTML page as a form to enter new attributes of the image searched and retrieved in the first web page.

Comment: @schwobaseggl How do I write a method for that in views.py?

Comment: You would have to change the url in your `urls.py`. Then your view signature would look like `def photo_edit(request, image_pk)` and you can go from there.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Can I request you to write an answer with the code please?

Comment: @KeerthanBhat what about doing the official tutorial and reading the doc instead of asking someone to write "the code" for you ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have done the tutorial and reading doc. Most of the times, it seemed cryptic and not beginner friendly. I am a beginner, only one month into Django.

Comment: It _is_ "beginner friendly" -  if you already know Python, SQL databases and web development. Else, well, Django's doc is not a web development 101 course nor a Python tutorial nor a SQL tutorial, so you do have to learn those things from dedicated resources indeed. You can of course try to build a project from copy-pasting codeyou don't understand from SO and/or other places but be sure the result will be a complete and unmaintainable mess at best.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers, okay. Thank you for the insight. I'll mend my ways of learning.

Comment: @KeerthanBhat then you might have a chance to succeed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this be passing the `ZSN` or the `Image` PK as an URL parameter to the next view. You need to do that because the actual `Image` instance can not be passed to the next view directly.

For example:

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/edit/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^home/photo-edit/(?P<photo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.photo_edit, name='photo-edit'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        image = Images.objects.filter(...).first()
        if image is not None:
            return redirect('photo-edit', image.pk)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid ZSN.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'cms/edit.html')

def photo_edit(request, image_pk):
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=image_pk)
    ...
```

Note how in this example the line `redirect('photo-edit', image.pk)` passes the image PK to the next view.
Now you would just need to implement the view `photo_edit` to fit your use case.

Let us know if that brings you closer to solving your problem.

Comment: image = Images.objects.filter(...).first()
        if image is not None:
            return redirect('photo-edit', image.pk) For this, its giving QuerySet has no attribute 'pk'.

Comment: But still URL isn't being found.

Comment: @KeerthanBhat what do you mean by "still URL isn't being found"? What is the error? When are you getting that error?