# TemplateDoesNotExist when using render to pass a parameter in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to add an edit feature to already uploaded images in my Content Management System built using Django.

```
@login_required
def edit(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ZSN = request.POST['ZSN']
        ZSN = 'images/' + ZSN + '.'

        image = Images.objects.filter(file__startswith=ZSN)

        if image:
            for im in image:
                pk = im.pk
            return render('/photo-edit/', pk)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid ZSN.")

    else:
        return render(request, 'cms/edit.html')

@login_required
def photoedit(request, image_pk):

    image = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=image_pk)
    return render(request, 'cms/photo-edit.html',{'image':image})
```

But because of this line, `return render('/photo-edit/', pk)` I'm getting a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception.

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/shadowsaint/Programs/my_project/templates/190 (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/shadowsaint/Programs/my_project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/190 (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/shadowsaint/Programs/my_project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/190 (Source does not exist)
```

Notice here 190 is the pk of the image being searched. Please help.

Comment: try return render(request,'cms/photo-edit/',pk)

Comment: Nope. Same error.

Comment: try return render(request,'cms/photo-edit.html',pk)  do you have photo-edit html under cms/templates/cms/photo-edit.html folder???

Comment: pk is an int. context has to be a dict. And see the answer below. That also suggests the same thing.

Comment: yes i know that you need t send context, but check your html file exist or not!! your getting this TemplateDoesNotExist error or different

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a parameter, the request variable. It works like this:

`render(request, 'template.html', context)`

So its reading your pk as the template name in this case.

Comment: How do I give pk and a template.html in the render()?

Comment: `render(request, 'your template name here.html', context={'pk': pk})`
Now you will have a context variable in your template called `pk` with the pk value.

Comment: But this directly goes to the template.html page. I want the image and its attributes to be there in the views.py method. Look at this. I have described the situation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516510/passing-information-between-web-pages-in-django.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect syntax `return render('/photo-edit/', pk)` as `/photo-edit/` MUST be an html file with an html extension. Trying to call your other view seems pointless in this aspect. Take what you have in `photoedit` view and just replace your `return render('/photo-edit/', pk)` with it. That will work how you expect.

Comment: So can I have GET and POST code inside a POST code?

Comment: I'm getting a view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead for this.

Comment: I don't think you understand what you are trying to do...can you explain the result you are trying to get? As well as your urls and your templates?